# selectize - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selectize.js

I'm trying to use standalone selectize library in my webapplication. But getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function
```

Here is my code:
In header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/selectize.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/selectize.default.css" >
```

In the html file

```
<label for="input-tags3">Skills</label>
<input id="input-tags3" name="skills" type="text" th:field="*{skills}" class="demo-default selectized text-input" value="science,biology,chemistry" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
<div class="selectize-control demo-default multi plugin-remove_button">
    <div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options has-items">
    <div class="item" data-value="science">science<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove" tabindex="-1" title="Remove">×</a></div>
    <div class="item" data-value="biology">biology<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove" tabindex="-1" title="Remove">×</a></div>
    <div class="item" data-value="chemistry">chemistry<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove" tabindex="-1" title="Remove">×</a></div>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="input-tags3-selectized" style="width: 4px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;">
</div>
    <div class="selectize-dropdown multi demo-default plugin-remove_button" style="display: none; width: 520px; top: 36px; left: 0px; visibility: visible;">
    <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
    <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="physics">physics</div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

In the js file

```
$('#input-tags3').selectize({
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    create: function(input) {
        return {
            value: input,
            text: input
        }
    }
});
```

What's missing?

Comment: Are you including jQuery? Where do you define `options`?

Comment: Yes, I've added <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: *Before* selectize? And where do you define `options`? **EDIT:** Per your edit: jQuery must be included before any jQuery plugins. You're currently including selectize *before* jQuery. **EDIT 2:** Can you please copy + paste your actual code? It's hard to know what your mistake is if you continuously edit them out.

Comment: I updated it, it's before selectize.

Comment: @TylerRoper sorry about that. last update is correct

Comment: @TylerRoper could be any issue with the version of jquery? or should I add sifter.js and microplugin,js?

Comment: @ImaMiri - would you care my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue fixed after adding the jquery at the beginning of the document.ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#input-tags3').selectize({
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    create: function(input) {
        return {
            value: input,
            text: input
        }
    }
});
....
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap `$('select').selectize();` by `$(function() {})` as follows in order to initialize jQuery prototype.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="selectize.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="selectize.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
    $('select').selectize(options);
});
</script>
```

Refer [here](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) to get details.

---

**PS**: For `options`, you could refer to the following examples:

- **Doc**
  https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#configuration
- **Example**
  https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/cities.html

```
...
$select_city = $('#select-city').selectize({
  valueField: 'name',
  labelField: 'name',
  searchField: ['name']
});
select_city = $select_city[0].selectize;
...
select_city.disable();
...
```

Comment: I used that but got error on options. Where should I define options? Sorry, I'm backend developer and recently started front end :|

Comment: @ImaMiri - I've updated my answer with post script(PS). Hope this might help you.

Comment: @ImaMiri - Just add **json-type** `options` following the API documentation. It's quite nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that doco. I have multiple select element in the page which they are normal select. If I add that script at the top of the page will impact the rest and I think that's why I get the error on options.

Comment: Got it. If so, I think you might separate individual options for every select element. Hope you'd got fixed your problem yet.